# Удаление поддеревьев из двоичного дерева поиска

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры-данных

В задаче имеем следующие входные данные:

6

-2 0 2

8 4 3

9 0 0

3 6 5

6 0 0

0 0 0

4

6 9 7 8

где первое число количество вершин двоичного дерева поиска, в последующих строках хранятся данные о вершинах. первое число это ключ вершины, второе - номер строки описания левого ребенка, третье - номер строки описания правого ребенка, если левого или правого ребенка нет то номер строки в котором они должны были описаны равен 0.
Следующие число - это количество запросов на удаление. Дальше идут ключи - корни поддеревьев, которые нужно удалить.

В выходных данных нужно вывести количество оставшихся вершин в дереве, после выполнения каждого запроса на удаление одного поддерева с заданным ключом. Поддерева с заданным ключом может не существовать.

В этом случае выходные данные будут следующими.

5
4
4
1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");


struct data
{
    int value, left, right;
    bool is_delete;
};


vector <data> data_tree;

int nodes = 0;

void input()
{
    int size_tree;

    in >> size_tree;

    if (size != 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < size_tree; i++)
        {
            data add;
            in >> add.value >> add.left >> add.right;

            add.is_delete = false;

            data_tree.push_back(add);
        }
    }
}


void remove(int index, int key)
{
    // если узел считается удаленным то не можем двигаться дальше
    if (data_tree[index].is_delete == true)return;

    // если узел равен нашему ключу то говорим, что он удален и выходим
    if (data_tree[index].value == key)
    {
        data_tree[index].is_delete = true;
        return;
    }

    // двигаемся дальше по дереву
    if (data_tree[index].left != 0)remove(data_tree[index].left - 1, key);

    if (data_tree[index].right != 0)remove(data_tree[index].right - 1, key);
 
    // считаем количество пройденных узлов
    nodes++;
}



void delete_sub_tree()
{
    int size_tree, key;
    in >> size_tree;

    // ввод запросов и удаление поддеревьев
    for (int i = 0; i < size_tree; i++)
    {
        nodes = 0;

        in >> key;

        remove(0, key);
        
        out << nodes << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{

    input();         // ввод данных

    delete_sub_tree(); // удаление поддеревьев

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Бинарное дерево строить не стал так как входные данные и так обладают достаточным и необходимым условием двоичного дерева поиска. (Каждый элемент имеет ссылку на левого и правого ребенка)

Удаление узла делать не стал так как это изменит расположение узлов в векторе, что нарушит структуру дерева, поэтому при удаление просто говориться, что поддерево с узлом удалено (bool is_delete).

Проблема в том, что данный алгоритм не проходит по времени с большим количеством данных. Начиная с 65000 вершин. Не знаю как можно ускорить этот алгоритм. Для того, чтобы найти в дереве узел с заданным ключем нужно обходить дерево начиная с корня (быстрее не придумаешь) O(log(n)). может быть input() замедляет работу программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В задаче `remove` вы не используете ключи вершин дерева и то-что в левом под-дереве все ключи меньше чем у головы, а во втором больше. И даже если в левой ветке вы нашли и удалили, то всё-равно почему-то продолжаете поиск во второй ветке. Это вам даёт ужасную скорость.

```
void remove(int index, int key  , int & nodes )
{

  // если узел считается удаленным то не можем двигаться дальше
  if (data_tree[index].is_delete == true)
    return;

  // если узел равен нашему ключу то говорим, что он удален и выходим
  if (data_tree[index].value == key)
  {
    data_tree[index].is_delete = true;
    -- nodes ;
    return;
  }

  // двигаемся дальше по дереву
  if (data_tree[index].value > key) {
    // проходим только левое поддерево
    if (data_tree[index].left != 0)
      remove(data_tree[index].left - 1, key);
    return ; }

  // проходим только правое поддерево
  if (data_tree[index].right != 0)
    remove(data_tree[index].right - 1, key); 
}
```

Comment: а как же пересчет вершин находящихся в другой ветке? ведь основная задача вывести количество вершин после удаления поддерева

Comment: а зачем их считать? нашли, и уменьшили на единицу. Если знали, сколько там.

Comment: вот добавил, если нашли, то уменьшаем общее кол-во